# Fixed Datalabel dimensions in Highcharts Series DataLabels

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

Im willing to achieve the following goal:

My highcharts chart has this series that has data-labels attached to each point, like in the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/p6Ufv/

The datalabels are supposed to be red circles (perfect circle), and therefore Iv'e used the following definition for them:

```
series{
//......////
dataLabels:{
        enabled : true,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(229, 32, 32)',
        borderRadius:24,
        borderWidth:2,
        borderColor: '#890000',
        color:'#FFF',
        shadow:true,
        defer:false,
        padding: 3,
 }
```

the following gives me a nice red circles with some stroke, when the point data is a 2 digit number.
the problem comes with numbers that have 1 digit, or more than 2.
for some reason, highcharts derives the Rect SVG dimensions from the datalabel content. this fact causes the datalabels become inconsistent in my design.
for some reason, I could not find a way to force highcharts to use `circle` instead of `rect` in the case of series datalabels, or, force it to render those SVG rects according to my dimension specifications.

Is this even possible? is there a way to work-around it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general you need to have a circle, because when I add 4 digits or remove all of them, datalebsl is circle. As I see in the code is used borderRadius, so you need to adapt height of datalbel and border radius parameter ot have circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a creative solution for my problem.
Iv'e created a circle image (could also use SVG), and used it as markers in the series. that made my series (which is also a scatter series) made of many circles. 
Than, I used some datalabel properties such as `padding` and `style` to make them look as I wanted. last thing I used a `formatter` to set the right data.

Comment: could you share this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this was part of a project Iv'e worked on in my job (which I'm not allowed to share). But I think my answer is pretty much straight-forward, but your'e welcome to ask me any question! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is inspired by @[MorKadosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625444/morkadosh)'s suggestion.

```js
import HighCharts from 'highcharts';

HighCharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.roundCircle = function (x, y, w, h) {
  let width = w,
    height = h,
    newX = x;
  if (height > width) {
    width = height;
    newX -= (width - w) / 2;
  } else if (width > height) {
    height = width;
  }
  return HighCharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.circle(newX, y, width, height);
};

{
  …,
  series: [{
    …,
    dataLabels: {
      …,
      shape: 'roundCircle'
    }
  }],
  …
}
```

Explanation:

The [series.line.marker.symbol](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.symbol) documentation references updating the Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols object, with a [link to a jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/).

The original circle function is as follows.

```js
f (a,b,k,t){return this.arc(a+k/2,b+t/2,k/2,t/2,{start:.5*Math.PI,end:2.5*Math.PI,open:!1})
```

In my example above we simply create a new function named roundCircle (an unfortunately redundant name) with a new function. Lines 7 - 12 make the width and height identical by making the smaller value equal to the larger value. If the width gets changed then the circle will get pushed to the right, making our value off-center, pushed to the left. We adjust by calculating how much the width has shifted, divide that by two, and then offsetting the x. The final statement simply calls the original circle function with our newly calculated values.

Finally, in our chart we define the series.dataLabels.shape value to "roundCircle".